# html5 application cache on ipad not working

Tags: html, ipad

I am designing on offline `html5` application, which works fine in desktop browser(IE, Chrome, Safari etc) and supports offline capability.

The same application will not work in iPad Safari Browser, but works fine in Chrome browser.
I have set the MIME type to text/cache-manifest and also validated my manifest file online which is fine.

Are there any special settings required for the application to make it work in ipad Safari?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in my cache `manifest` was
1. I specify the homepage as "/" that need to be cached.

The above works fine on all browsers except on iPad which throws error.
I have removed the "/" that represent home page from the cache section. It works fine now on all the browsers including iPad.

Comment: Any chance you can include the working code? Both html and manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure the cache.manifest file only uses relative URLs not ABSOLUTE.
2. Ensure the cache.manifest was saved in right charset in your IDE/Text redactor
3. Don't include page where cache.manifest is inited (page with `<html manifest="cache.manifest">`)