# HTML5 offline cache not working on iPad only

Tags: ios, html, offline-caching

I'm using offline cache to make my HTML5 app available in offline mode. This works perfectly fine on all desktop browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari - I don't care about IE) as well as on android chrome, iOS Chrome and even Safari on iPhone.  However on iPad safari it does not work.

Using the now-standard [cache debug routine by Jonathan Stark](https://jonathanstark.com/blog/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache?filename=2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/) and debugging via Safari on my mac, I see the following in my console:

```
[Log] online: yes, event: checking, status: downloading (cachedebug.js, line 30)
[Log] online: yes, event: downloading, status: downloading (cachedebug.js, line 30)
[Log] online: yes, event: progress, status: downloading (cachedebug.js, line 30, x159)
[Log] online: yes, event: progress, status: updateready (cachedebug.js, line 30)
[Log] online: yes, event: updateready, status: updateready (cachedebug.js, line 30)
[Log] swap cache has been called (cachedebug.js, line 37)
[Error] InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
    swapCache (main.js:407)
    (anonymous function) (main.js:407)
```

Note the error at the end.  I did commend the `swapCache` line in Jonathan's code. This occurs almost always on iPad Safari - but not on any other device/browser.  I did try removing all data for my site in Safari Settings - to no avail.

As a result, the app never caches fully and therefore I cannot run it while offline.

For the record, my main file starts with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" manifest="cache.manifest">
```

And the code in main.js looks like this:

```
 403 function setupAppCacheListeners() {
 404     var appCache = window.applicationCache;
 405     appCache.addEventListener("downloading", function() { toast("Downloading an update - please do not close the application."); });
 406     appCache.addEventListener("updateready", function() {
 407         appCache.swapCache();
 408         toast("Updates downloaded successfully - please restart the application.", 0);
 409         $('#button-refresh').removeClass('hidden');
 410     });
 411     appCache.addEventListener("cached", function() { toast("Download for offline use completed."); });
up to date."); });
 412     appCache.addEventListener("error", function() {
 413         if(navigator.onLine) {
 414             toast("An error occurred updating the app - please try restarting.");
 415         }
 416     });
 417 }
```

Interestingly enough, this application is a fork of another application that I wrote a couple of years ago, which works absolutely fine with no such problem.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Saw it and tried it - no difference

Comment: @NikolaLukic thanks. There is only one HTML document and no iframes.

Comment: Maybe not elegant : use  try and catch or detect ipad and then  just call window.reload(true) only for ipad...

Comment: How it looks intro manifest ,   fileImage1.png   or  /fileImage.png . Last answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039770/html5-application-cache-on-ipad-not-working?rq=1

Comment: The manifest is fine; all paths are relative. It works on all other devices except iPad

Comment: @AleksG Did you find a solution? Having issues with iPad too -- Chrome works, but iPad fails. Any ideas?